# Make a control center menu for media control

Tags: ios, objective-c

i saw some app come with a menu in the control center,I search the app document,but found nothing about this.

My question is How this work?is the new api on ios9?

[image: the control command as you can see at here][image: lock screen menu too][image: the menu can be change]

update: the translate chinese to english

[image]

Comment: I'm betting it's the MPPlayableContentManager.

Comment: @matt but as i check,it shows
MPPlayableContentManager and MPContentItem class are only used for CarPlay. Using it requires a special entitlement issued by Apple.

Comment: I know... But maybe this is how CarPlay apps look on the device. I've never used a CarPlay app, so I don't know. When you find out the right answer, please tell me!

Comment: (I forgot to ask - could you translate the menus into English? What do they say? Maybe that will give us a clue!)

Comment: @matt i update a picture,and the app is:https://itunes.apple.com/cn/app/dou-banfm/id353732572?mt=8

but i think it only available at china.